# Как сделать чтобы метод класса возвращал значение а не undefined?

Tags: javascript

Возникла проблема функция `summary` выдает `undefined` так как ничего не возвращает. Как сделать так чтобы функция `summary` возвращала  `Cool!` ,  `Good, but it can be better!` , `Radish`.
Я просто не очень понимаю как в return передать условия при которых будет выводиться конкретный текст.

```
summary () {
  const averageVisit = this.visitinMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length / this.visitinMagazine.length;
  if (this.avgMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
    return console.log('Cool!');
  } else if (this.avgMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
    return console.log('Good, but it can be better!');
  } else {
    return console.log('Radish');
  }
}
```

Comment: Передать в `return` значение, а не `console.log()`, потому что `console.log()` не возвращяет ничего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно так

```
summary () {
  const averageVisit = this.visitinMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length / this.visitinMagazine.length;
  if (this.avgMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
    return 'Cool!';
  } else if (this.avgMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
    return 'Good, but it can be better!';
  } else {
    return 'Radish';
  }
}
```

Или вот так

```
summary () {
  const averageVisit = this.visitinMagazine.filter((element) => element === true).length / this.visitinMagazine.length;
  let returnString;
  if (this.avgMark > 90 && averageVisit > 0.9) {
    returnString = 'Cool!';
  } else if (this.avgMark > 90 || averageVisit > 0.9) {
    returnString = 'Good, but it can be better!';
  } else {
    returnString = 'Radish';
  }
  return returnString;
}
```